# sendmail.exe" -t' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, batch-file, xampp, sendmail

Having some issues with Sendmail on Xampp (Windows Installation) - When I try a test Email (See below script)

```
<?php 
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$from = "xxx@xxx.com";
$to = "xxx@xxx.com";
$subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
$message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

Upon running this script and checking the error.log I get the following error:

```
'D:\Xampp2\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My settings look like so:

**PHP.ini**

```
XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like    Mercury
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_from = katosart@gmail.com
sendmail_path="D:\xampp2\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**Sendmail.ini**

```
smtp_server= smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port= 465
smtp_ssl= auto
auth_username=katosart@gmail.com
auth_password=(HIDDEN)
```

I have tried using ports of: 587, 465, 25 for the smtp_port area.
Rather stumped on this one - any ideas please? :)

Comment: What's the stray escaped `\"` double quote supposed to do?

Comment: Can I ask where you mean sorry? :)

Comment: I found where you meant, sorry it should have been: "\"D:\xampp2\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" - which I got from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Comment: GMail requires a separate SMTP per-application password. Though you should rather get rid of that mail()+sendmail.exe workaround. Just use PHPMailer/SwiftMailer instead.

Comment: Not used either before to be honest, I'll look into tutorials for both. Thanks Mario

Answer (score 0):

OK! So I have worked this out myself by commenting out:

```
sendmail_path="D:\xampp2\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

However, I now got an Email from Google saying:

```
We recently blocked a sign-in attempt to your Google Account
```

So the emails are getting through.
I worry that this may impact on **other** recipients receiving the same issue?

EDIT:
Getting an error on the running of the above script, the error is:

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. q2sm18977843wjz.15 - gsmtp in D:\xampp2\htdocs\test-email.php on line 9
```

Comment: I've allowed access for less secure apps, retested the script and now get: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. q2sm18977843wjz.15 - gsmtp in D:\xampp2\htdocs\test-email.php on line 9